# keytool -import failed with the error "failed to establish chain from reply"

Tags: certificate, keytool, ca

I have a keystore, which contains only 1 keypair (foo). From that keypair, I generated a csr, which was signed by a CA using the certificate bar (bar is the issuer of foo). The issue I have is that I'm unable to import back the certificate foo in my keystore with this command

```
keytool -importcert -alias foo -file foo.p7b keypass 123456 -keystore keystore.jks -storepass 123456
```

It failed with the error

```
Failed to establish chain from reply.
```

If add the public certificate bar in my keystore, then it is working fine.

Therefore, one will simply think that I absolutely need to insert the public certificate bar in my keystore, but what is bugging me here is that if I use KeyStore Explorer to import the certificate foo in my keystore (which is only containing the keypair foo), then it is working fine. In other word, I able to import the certificate with KeyStore Explorer ("Import CA reply"), but not keytool.

Is anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: There is a setting in the preferences ("Trust Checks") of KeyStore Explorer where you can enable/disable the check for a trusted CA certificate. By default this check is disabled, that is why you see the difference between keytool and KSE. There are many scenarios where it just makes no sense to check the certificate chain when importing a certificate. Therefore I prefer KeyStore Explorer's default behavior.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, it is really helpfull. Is there a way to bypass that "trust checks" with keytool ? I mean, I may be wrong, but I'm guessing that KeyStore Explorer is calling keytool to perform the command, so there should be a way to do the same in command line...

Comment: No, KeyStore Explorer is not calling keytool. There are a lot of things you can do with KSE that are not possible with keypool (e.g. private key export, conversion between Java and OpenSSL key formats, appending/deleting certificates in a chain, ...).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for you help